# Javascript, Java data and error

Tags: javascript, java

I'm trying to make a connection between my java code and javascript. There is a check for success or error in my JS, but this is not exactly what I need:

```
function loginGebruiker() {
var uri = "/slaapapp/restservices/login/"

$
        .ajax(
                uri,
                {
                    type : "post",
                    data : $("#loginform").serialize(),
                    dataType : String,
                    success : function(response) {
                        if (data == null)
                            alert("no");
                        else
                            alert("ok");

                    },
                    error : function(response) {
                        alert("Something wrong..");
                    }
                });
};
```

However this does not work, seeing how I get a nullpointer error out of my Java code. If I change the returns in that code, though, it just brings me to an empty page with only the String there.

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
public String Login(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("wachtwoord") String wachtwoord) {
    GebruikerDAO dao = new GebruikerDAO();
    Gebruiker g = dao.VindUsername(username);

    if (g.getWachtwoord().equals(wachtwoord)) {
        return "success";
    }

    return null;
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this and that I formulated my question properly, thanks in advance!

Comment: Off-topic but I would advise either using Dutch or English language. You are mixing quite a lot in your code. ("Wachtwoord" en "Username").

Comment: You did a pretty good job at formulating the question.  Check out [ask], [mcve], and [help/on-topic] to learn more about asking questions on SO.  You can also check out [answer] if you want to answer any questions on SO.

Comment: Your javascript does nothing other than displaying an alert message. What do you expect to see? BTW, error() only kicked in if the server return not 200. Do you not see any "alert" display?

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen: Thanks for the tip, will keep it in mind!

Comment: @MinhKieu The alert does not get displayed like you mentioned, whether the code succeeds or not it returns me to a page with just the returns from the public String (depending on the outcome which String gets displayed of course)

Comment: use something like firebug to inspect the response from the server. Your JS code POST the data and displays an ALERT. I sees no code to render or display what the server return?

Comment: `dataType : String,` looks incorrect. It should be `dataType: 'text'` or `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @styfle I tried both, and it changes nothing

Comment: @MinhKieu that could be right, but I have no idea how to read the data or anything for that matter.

Comment: Time to debug, you need to know if Java server-side code is being triggered or 404. Also, you need to understand how to track the JS call to the backend. Look at the "Net" tab or "XHR" tab to see the request/response. Sorry, I can't be more help as these are the basic skills.